# Iteración dentro de una iteración con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hace poco me decidí a tomar un curso de javascript y uno de sus ejercicios era hacer un botón que al ejecutarse mostraría una lista de animales creados mediante clases y se mostraría en pantalla mediante una lista. No quise hacerlo tan sencillo y quise que se mostraran los distintos animales en tres divs diferentes, pero el texto que me aparece es `undefined` y la verdad no logro entender el porqué.
Acá les dejo el código:

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h1> &#x1F43E; Listado de Mascotas</h1>
        <button class="botonsto" onclick="mostrarLista()">
            <span>Ver listado</span>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 13 10" height="10px" width="15px">
                <path d="M1,5 L11,5"></path>
                <polyline points="8 1 12 5 8 9"></polyline>
              </svg></button>
        <div class="containerInfo" id="divContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Primero hice una clase con sus propiedades y un método que me devolviera un string con los valores de dichas propiedades:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor (nombre, peso, edad){
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._peso = peso;
    this._edad = edad;   
    }
    informacion (){
        return `${this.nombre} - ${this.peso}kg - ${this.edad} años.`;
    }
}
```

Luego creé 3 instancias de cada subclase, es decir 3 perros, 3 gatos y 3 conejos y eso los agregué a un array y a su vez a esas listas las inserté en otro array:

```js
    //Crear array que contiene la informacion de los tres objetos (Conejos) para luego mostrarlos
    let listaPerros = [perro1, perro2, perro3];
    let listaGatos = [gato1, gato2, gato3];
    let listaConejos = [conejo1, conejo2, conejo3];

    //crear un array de lista de listas 
    let listaDeAnimales = [listaPerros, listaGatos, listaConejos];
```

Ya por último desarrollé la función que va a crear los div y las listas para mostrar la información (aquí es donde está el problema):

```js
function mostrarLista(){

        let elementoContainer = document.getElementById('divContainer');

        for (let clase of listaDeAnimales) {

            //creando elementos div / ul /
            let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            let newUL = document.createElement ('ul'); 
            //asignando atributos y insertando elementos
            
            newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'item');
            elementoContainer.appendChild(newDiv);            
            newDiv.appendChild(newUL);
            newUL.setAttribute('id', 'listaAnimales');            
            //creando otro loop para mostrar la info
            for (let animal of clase) {
                
                let item = document.createElement('li');
                item.innerText = animal.informacion();
                newUL.appendChild(item);
                
            }                         
        
        }
```

Comment: Hola Oscar. Un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo funciona como las horas, minutos y segundos. Por ejemplo, por cada hora hay sesenta minutos. Antes de pasar a la segunda hora, tienen que pasar 60 minutos. Pues en arrays anidados es lo mismo: antes de pasar a la siguiente iteración del array externo, se tiene que iterar por completo el array interno. Un saludo y bienvenido

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema está en este fragmento de código:

```
informacion (){
    return `${this.nombre} - ${this.peso}kg - ${this.edad} años.`;
}
```

Estás accediendo a miembros de clase (`nombre`, `peso` y `edad`) que no existen, ya que en tu constructor los declaras como `_nombre`, `_peso` y `_edad`.

Puedes cambiar la función `informacion()` así:

```
informacion (){
    return `${this._nombre} - ${this._peso}kg - ${this._edad} años.`;
}
```

O cambiar el constuctor de tu clase `Animal` de esta forma:

```
constructor (nombre, peso, edad){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.edad = edad;   
}
```